# Can't get wifi adapter MT7601U to work on ubuntu server 22.04 for raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, server, wireless-adapter

I bought this generic wifi adapter which has MT7601U wifi chip inside it, it doesn’t work on my Ubuntu server 22.04 OS

But the adapter works fine out of the box on my twisterOS installation

Am i missing something? I found a post online and it says the adapter is supposed to work just fine from 16.04 and onwards since the drivers are included in kernel 4.2+

Does Ubuntu server not include all the wifi adapters drivers in it, or is it removed?

(all related images in the link below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHlOw.jpg